# index out of range error when profiling go program

Tags: go

[This](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) blog post provides instructions about how to profile a golang program using the `runtime/pprof` package.

In addition to the above mentioned package import, it says (STEP 1) to add this code to the main func

```
var cpuprofile = flag.String("cpuprofile", "", "write cpu profile to file")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if *cpuprofile != "" {
        f, err := os.Create(*cpuprofile)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)
        defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    }
```

Then (STEP2) to run the binary (in this case named ./havlak1) passing the name of a file (with extension .prof) to the cpuprofile flag

```
 ./havlak1 -cpuprofile=havlak1.prof
```

Then, after the program stops, (STEP 3) to pass the binary and the `.prof` file to the `go tool pprof` program

```
$ go tool pprof havlak1 havlak1.prof
Welcome to pprof!  For help, type 'help'.
(pprof)
```

At this point, the blog author runs the 
`top10` command to get some output.

I have done each of those steps with my program (but with different binary and .prof file name).  However, when I run the `top10` command, my program panics with an index out of range error. If I do

```
cat myfile.prof
```

to check the contents of the `.prof` file, there is no output.

Question: is there a step missing in the blog post or what might I be doing wrong or not doing for the `.prof` file to be empty?

**Update**

Just to clarify, after starting the binary with the cpu flag like this

**./havlak1 -cpuprofile=havlak1.prof**

I visit the routes of my application a bunch of times to give it an opportunity to collect data. After I stop the program, I do `cat filename.prof` and it's empty

Once I run this command

```
go tool pprof havlak1 havlak1.prof
```

I can obviously no longer click around my application because the binary isn't running. (I'm assuming the binary is passed to the `go tool pprof havlak1` for reasons other than to run the program again/keep it running)

**Update**

Do I have to include code to manually close the file it writes to? I am able to profile my application using a wrapper program `github.com/davecheney/profile`, which has a line that closes the file that's been opened.

Comment: I'd say you gotta be missing something. I think you're following the main steps, what happens after this code? `top10` is expecting that file to be full of data and giving you the top10 items based off whatever ordering is used. I would guess the profiler isn't collecting any data or has nothing to profile since a failure to write would probably result in a panic at that time. So chances are, the file is created and opened correctly but you're collecting no data to write there.

Comment: try running your code longer, the profiler needs some repetition to be able to output proper data.

Comment: I ran the program again, this time longer, clicking on routes which is making the server generate a lot of data, still absolutely no output when I do `cat filename.prof` and the panic happens when I do `top10` or any other command after starting `go tool pprof...`. By the way, when I do run `go tool pprof`, do I pass the binary just by name i.e. `havlak1` or as I would start it i.e. `./havlak1`. Either way in my case, I get the panic if I try to do `top10`

Comment: I'm certainly doing something wrong when trying to use it (i.e. nothing's broken) because when I try to gather data using this wrapper https://github.com/davecheney/profile it works fine  and gathers data immediately

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the file isn't being written and it looks like you are using a defer for the profile to stop. If the application exits before that defer can run you won't get the profile written.

You could try to stop the profiling at the end without using a defer statement.

You could make sure the issue is your code and not your machine by writing a simple test and running `go test --cpuprofile=cpu.prof` ( all go tests can be profiled using that flag automatically) and then viewing the results by `go tool pprof mypackage.test cpu.prof`

Comment: The problem certainly seems to be the code because I can gather profile data using this wrapper for the tooling https://github.com/davecheney/profile, just not do it without the wrapper

Comment: Try to manually stop the profiler and close the file before exiting